# How can I make sure that my currency converter displays if above clip limit? (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, currency, converters

I am trying to create a converter for currencies that keeps into consideration clip limit by countries.

I went as far as creating a function that displays status of clip level according to a fix variable:

```
input1 = str(input('Enter Currency [CZK or PLN]: '))
value1 = float(input('Enter Value: '))

if input1 == 'PLN' or 'Pln' or 'pln':
    value2 = value1/3
    if input1 == 'CZK' or 'Czk' or 'czk':
        value2 = value1/20
else: print('Some error occurred, try again.')

round(value2,2)
print('The conversion of ', value1, input1, 'is: ', value2,'USD \n')

if value2 >= 20:
    print('ABOVE Clip level - EU PO is required')
else: print('BELOW clip level')
print('value ',value2,'USD matches expected.')
```

As you can see the code is quite rudimentary and take into consideration made-up conversion rates.
What I would like to achieve is that the function returns that value is ABOVE/BELOW clip level according to a chosen country. So for example I have in place CKZ and PLN as currencies, therefore I would use CZ and PL).

Such function is not implemented in the code yet because I am not sure how to proceed.
Would you be able to help? Thank you!

**Edit > run code by Younes:**
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/12g2D.png)

Comment: Your problem isn't clear to me. You say you want the function to return a value but there is no function here. Do you want to create a new one? Do you want to bundle your code in a function?
Also you say you want it to return (if?) the value is above or below a certain threshold. Is this threshold a parameter?  Does it depend on the currency.
If you have issues with the concept of function in python please refer to: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line here :

```
else: print('Some error occurred, try again.')
```

requires a loop to start with. You want to create a function and then call it inside a loop, this might do :

```
def f(country,value):

    if "PL" in country.upper():
        value2 = value/3
    elif "CZ" in country.upper():
        value2 = value/20
    else: 
        raise ValueError
    round(value2,2)
    print('The conversion of ', value1, input1, 'is: ', value2,'USD \n')

    if value2 >= 20:
        print('ABOVE Clip level - EU PO is required')
        return('ABOVE Clip level')
    else: 
        print('value {} USD matches expected.'.format(value2))
        return('BELOW clip level')
    
while True:

    input1 = str(input('Enter Currency [CZK or PLN]: '))
    value1 = float(input('Enter Value: '))

    try :
        f(input1,value1)
        break
    except ValueError:
        print('Some error occurred, try again.')
```